# Extend model in Ruby on Rails for RESTful api app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, oop, multi-table-inheritance

As a part of a project we got an UML diagram to implement. Now I'm at the part of OOP, but I'm not sure how to implement that in Ruby.
Every Task is a Chore or Homework, as I understand it must be multi table inheritance(MTI).
I'm not sure how to implement the relations between users table -> chores/hw's tables , also tasks->chores/hw's tables.
Also, it will be good to know how to implement the CRUD actions (create\update\destroy)
Hope somebody can help.
Thanks.
Here is the diagram:
[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHkgI.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
models/person.rb
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tasks, as: :owner, class_name: "::Task"
end

models/task.rb
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true

  enum status: {
    active: 0,
    done: 1
  }

  scope :chores, -> { where(type: "Tasks::Chores")}
  scope :homeworks, -> { where(type: "Tasks::Homework")}
end

models/tasks/chores.rb
class Tasks::Chores < Task
  enum size: {
    small: 0,
    medium: 1,
    large: 2
  }
end

models/tasks/homework.rb
class Tasks::Homework
end
```

I haven't tried this code but it should be correct.

`Task` has a polymorphic `owner`, so it can be a `Person`, or any other model, this will add 2 columns `owner_type` and `owner_id`.

A task also has a `type` (STI) which can be either `Tasks::Chores` or `Tasks::Homework` (which I namespaced for clarity)

Using the scopes on the `Task` model you should be able to call `person.tasks.chores` or `person.tasks.homeworks`

Comment: But every type of Task has different fields, it dosen't mean that with STI I'll get a records with some nulls?

Comment: In STI you can't add specific fields to the children records because they don't have a specific table in the database.
What you should do is add all the fields to the parent Task model, bu yes you will end up with fields being empty if you don't use them on the child record. This is generally not a problem though

Answer (score 0):

Even though your UML schema violates [Dependency Inversion principle](https://betterprogramming.pub/straightforward-simple-dependency-inversion-vs-dependency-injection-7d8c0d0ed28e#:%7E:text=Dependency%20inversion%20is%20a%20design,agnostic%20towards%20the%20implementation%20details.) when implement it in Rails and violates [2NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form)

But you can do it like this:

You need to create two tables `people` and `tasks`

You can do this by adding these migrations:

```rb
class CreatePeople < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :people do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.string :fav_prog_lang
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
class CreateTasks < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :tasks do |t|
      t.references :owner, null: false, foreign_key: { to_table: :people }
      t.text :description
      t.integer :size, default: 0
      t.string :course
      t.datetime :due_date
      t.string :details
      t.integer :status, default: 0
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

After that you need to create these models:

```rb
# app/models/person.rb

class Person < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tasks, foreign_key: :owner_id
end
```

```rb
# app/models/task.rb

class Task < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'Person', foreign_key: :owner_id

  enum status: { active: 0, done: 1 }
end
```

```rb
# app/models/chore.rb

class Chore < Task
  enum size: { small: 0, medium: 1, large: 2 }
end
```

```rb
# app/models/homework.rb

class Homework < Task
  enum size: { small: 0, medium: 1, large: 2 }, _prefix: true
end
```

And finnaly you are able to create you tasks:

```rb
person = Person.create(name: 'John Doe', email: 'john.doe@test.test', fav_prog_lang: 'Ruby')

Homework.create(owner: person, course: 'Some course', due_date: 10.days.since, details: 'Some details')

Chore.create(owner: person, size: :medium, description: 'Some description')

person.tasks
```

If you need to be able to know what task is `chore` and what task is `homework` you need to add `type` field to the `tasks` table so that to be able to determine subtask

**Update:**

To avoid violating Dependency Inversion principle you can do next:

Separate `Task`, `Chore` and `Homework` to different tables since `Chore` and `Homework` have very different fields

```rb
class CreateTasks < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :tasks do |t|
      t.references :owner, null: false, foreign_key: { to_table: :people }
      t.integer :status, default: 0

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
class CreateChores < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :chores do |t|
      t.references :task, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.text :description
      t.integer :size, default: 0
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
class CreateHomeworks < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :homeworks do |t|
      t.references :task, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.string :course
      t.datetime :due_date
      t.string :details
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And than your models:

```rb
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tasks, foreign_key: :owner_id
  has_many :chores, through: :tasks
  has_many :homeworks, through: :tasks
end
```

```rb
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'Person', foreign_key: :owner_id
  has_many :chores
  has_many :homeworks

  enum status: { active: 0, done: 1 }
  
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :chores, :homeworks
end
```

```rb
class Chore < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :task
  enum size: { small: 0, medium: 1, large: 2 }
end
```

```rb
class Homework < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :task
end
```

And you can manipulate those models like this:

```rb
person = Person.create(name: 'John Doe', email: 'john.doe@test.test', fav_prog_lang: 'Ruby')

person.tasks.create(
  status: :done, chores_attrubutes: [{ size: :medium, description: 'Some description' }]
)

person.tasks.create(homeworks_attrubutes: [{ course: 'Some course', due_date: 10.days.since, details: 'Some details' }])


person.chores

person.homeworks

# and you can have also all tasks

person.tasks
```

**Note: But this approach is not suitable if you will need to add more different tasks. Because all the time you will have a new task type you will have to add new table. This only works for your current example.**

Comment: That was my intuition too. I have some questions: 1.What is a _prefix:true means? 2. When implementing CRUDs (e.g create, do i have to call super command too?

Comment: Using a prefix (or suffix) on an enum gives you access to methods: in this case using .size_large? will return a boolean depending on what is stored in the DB.
In your controllers you will not have to use super you should just add a controller for each type of task

Comment: Since `small?` is reserved word in Rails and by adding `enum` with option `small` Rails tries to rewrite this method that's why we need to add prefix to size enum. And ckeck my update what to do to avoid dependency inversion violation